# How to load a ruby file in to IRB?

Tags: ruby

I have a file: `options.rb`
I open IRB and type:

```
require './options.rb'
 #=> true
```

Try to call a variable in the `options` file such as `key` *(yes this variable is there and the file is saved)*

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `key' for main:Object
from (irb):2
```

Why is this **not** working? *By the way* also tried to load the file as: `irb -r ./options.rb`

**UPDATE**

Also tried to do `load './options.rb'` which does return `#=> true` but this also does not work.

Comment: What's the file path of the file you're trying to require?

Comment: Niether `load` nor `require` propagate local variables into the global namespace. So you will have to use some other way if you want to access variables inside the `options` file.

Comment: @Casper what is that other way because using globals or constants is annoying and copy pasting to IRB is equally disturbing.

Comment: Some other ways: a) Use a module `MyModule.some_key`, b) Use class methods `MyClass.some_key`, c) Define a method `some_key`, d) Use instance variables `@some_key`, e) Eval it specifically in the `irb` binding `eval(File.read(...), IRB.conf[:MAIN_CONTEXT].workspace.binding)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`require` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require):

> Any constants or globals within the loaded source file will be available in the calling program’s global namespace. However, local variables will not be propagated to the loading environment.

So if in `options.rb` you  have something like:

```
key = something
```

(i.e. `key` is a local in the file) then it will not be available in irb. If you make it a global (e.g. `$key = 'something'`) or a constant (e.g. `KEY = 'something'`) it should be available.

Comment: Yes this is what I need. That's annoying though. Tried to do `eval(File.read('./options.rb'),binding)` which also doesn't work. Annoying that my only option is copy and paste to irb or use global or constants everywhere. There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not like global variables (as [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt) suggested) you might also make it an instance variable of the object `irb` is running on (an instance of `Object` available through `self` as ruby *always* has an object it is operating on) you may also assign

```
@key='value'
```

in your file which will give you access to `@key` in your `irb`-session afterwards. This will work with either `require` as with `load`, but `require` will only `load` the file if it has not already done so while `load` will always execute the code in the file and thus will end up overwriting the contents of your variable if it has been changed in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is a interpreted language, so for the interpreter to notice your declarations you need to actually 'run' them, the corresponding command in irb is

load './options.rb'

Comment: Tried using `load` too. returns `true` but still doesn't work